# Accessing properties of one QML file from another QML file AND vice versa

Tags: qml, qt5

I have two QML files. PageOne.qml and PageTwo.qml.
I want to access elements' properties and methods in PageOne.qml from PageTwo.qml and in PageTwo.qml from PageOne.qml.
I can gain access to PageOne.qml from PageTwo.qml by including

```
PageOne{
    id: pageOne
}
```

in PageTwo.qml. Piece of cake.

But if I add

```
PageTwo{
    id: pageTwo
}
```

to PageOne.qml to achieve my main goal my application doesn't start. I get no errors.
What is the proper method to do it?

Comment: When you created PageOne.qml and have an item `PageOne {}` in the .qml file, and when you tried to embed the `PageOne{}` in PageTwo.qml file it will be same as any other qml item (like say `Rectangle {}`) that you embed in your PageTwo.qml. Now if you try to embed `PageTwo{}` (which already has PageOne item in it) in to PageOne.qml I think its going to be recursive. You don't see any errors when you build. But you see problems when you trying to deploy.

Comment: I suggest you to have the logic in cpp and try to use signal/slots in the respective qml files.

Comment: I don't use C++, I use Python with pyotherside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I declared a function in PageTwo.qml

```
PageOne{
   id: pageOne
   function myfunc(arg){
        idOfAnElementInPageTwo.func(arg)
}
```

Then I called this function from PageOne.qml and it worked! So I need to explicitly define methods to change/call methods in another file.

Answer (score 0):

Just move your logic to a `js` file and include it in both qml files.

For example, you can create MyLogic.js with the following content:

```
.pragma library

function myPrettyComplexFunction(...)
{
    ...
}
```

And later in your qml files you will include and use it like this:

```
import "MyLogic.js" as MyLogic
...
MyLogic.myPrettyComplexFunction(...)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found your question by accident while searching for unrelated question,
and although it may be irrelevant to you at this point I decided to answer
since I researched similar problem as some point myself

### Infinite inheritence

Defining `PageTwo.qml` as `PageOne {...}`
is similar to inheriting in C++:

```cpp
class PageTwo: public PageOne {...};
```

Obviously, you cannot **both** inherit `PageOne` from `PageTwo` **and also** `PageTwo` from `PageOne`, because `PageOne` would contain `PageTwo` which would contain `PageOne` infinitely ...

But let's assume that `PageTwo` inherits `PageOne` - this should be ok for your situation

### Forward references

You cannot access elements from other QML files by their `id` - this is intentional
All non-root elements are like `private` members in C++

Unfortunately, QML does not allow `protected` members or `friend` classes

But you can expose internal elements making them "public".
To do so you must provide an `property alias` in root element of QML file like this:

**PageOne.qml**:

```js
Column {
    Text { id: pageOnePrivateElement; text: "test" }
    property alias pageOnePublicElement: pageOnePrivateElement 
}
```

**PageTwo.qml**

```js
PageOne {
     Text { text: pageOnePublicElement.text } //works
     Text { text: pageOnePrivateElement.text } //doesn't work
}
```

You then need to do `Window { PageTwo{} }` - `PageOne` will load automatically

### Backward references

This works but doesn't allow IDs from `PageTwo` to work in `PageOne`

To do that you would simply need to create and assign properties:

**PageOne.qml**:

```js
Column {
    property Text pageTwoPublicElement
     Text { text: pageTwoPublicElement.text } //works
     Text { text: pageTwoPrivateElement.text } //doesn't work
}
```

**PageTwo.qml**

```js
PageOne {
    Text { id: pageTwoPrivateElement; text: "test" }
    pageTwoPublicElement: pageTwoPrivateElement 
}
```

### Caveat emptor

Please note that it may be possible for `pageTwoPublicElement` to be `null` or `undefined` for a short while until `PageTwo.qml` is fully loaded.

This may result in errors trying to access properties of `undefined` object even if it is very clearly defined.

If you encounter such a problem you may need to check elements before using:

```js
     Text { text: ( null !== pageTwoPublicElement 
                    && undefined !== pageTwoPublicElement ) 
                    ? pageTwoPublicElement.text : "" }
```

If you are not careful, you may end up with `binding loop` - a property that depends on something that depends on that same property, maybe indirectly.
Such errors are usually diagnosed by commenting out code until error message disappears.